# scala regex weird behavior

Tags: regex, scala

```
scala> val p = "ab|ba|(ab)*a|(ba)*b".r
p: scala.util.matching.Regex = ab|ba|(ab)*a|(ba)*b

scala> val m = p.pattern.matcher _
m: java.lang.CharSequence => java.util.regex.Matcher = <function1>

scala> m("aa").matches
res9: Boolean = false

scala> p.findAllIn("aa").toList
res10: List[String] = List(a, a)
```

"aa" should not be matched, as per res9. But res10 says there are 2 matches. How do you explain this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aa` will be matched because you use `find`.

`(ab)*a` will match `a`.

Maybe you want an expression like:

```
^(?:ab|ba|(?:ab)*a|(?:ba)*b)$
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted the experession you've typed, not the one I came up with. If you don't mind, can you explain how you came up with it.

Comment: @kr, group the alterations and add the anchors `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the pattern. `^` matches beginning of string, `$` matches end of string.

Comment: I know the meanings of ^ and $, but what does (?:ab) mean ? Thanks.

Comment: @kr, non-capturing group, same as `(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You are asking two different things:

When you use `m("aa").matches`, you are asking whether the whole string `aa` corresponds to the pattern `m`.

When you use `p.findAllIn("aa").toList`, you are asking whether there are *substrings* of `aa` that correspond to the pattern `m`.

So, yes, there are substrings that match `m`, but the full string `aa` itself doesn't.